# How do I make a basic typeahead search of JSON data using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead, search-box

I have a JSON data file stored locally on my PC. The file is an array of various "name": "value". For instance -

```
[
 {
  "name": "Joe",
  "id": "0",
  "age": "24",
},
 {
  "name": "Mary",
  "id": "1",
  "age": "25",
}
]
```

Now I need to make a typeahead search box for this kind of JSON data using javascript.
The code I wrote is displayed in the image:

[image: image1]

Where "dummy" is the name of my locally stored JSON file. The code is not displaying the suggestive data from the JSON file and just gives me an input search box to enter stuff. How do I make it work? Kindly correct me and help.

Comment: *"How do I make it work"* is too vague a question . See [ask]. Be specific and also tell us about errors thrown(if any)

Comment: You should [edit] the code into the question, rather than include an image of the code.